# FLASH Auto Looping Disable

Tags: flash, loops

I have an animation and I want it to play it just only once. From where can I set so when I export to SWF the default will be AUTO LOOPING disabled.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert a keyframe in the last frame and put a stop(); there?

Comment: Yes that's the best way to ensure it works regardless of any other settings

Answer (score 0):

Please following code

```
<param name='loop' value='false' />

<object type='application/x-shockwave-flash' data='sourcefile' width='300' height='120' loop='false'>
```

This works perfectly